# Change parts of a line containing string using bash (macos)

Tags: bash, macos

I need to identify lines in a music playlist file .m3u containing the string ' [LD]' and update those lines with specific changes.

For example:

`/music/Miles Davis/1959 - Kind of Blue [LD]/Miles Davis - So What.mp3`

Needs to become:

`/music/_lossless/Miles Davis/1959 - Kind of Blue/Miles Davis - So What.mp3`

ie. the string '_lossless/' is inserted after '/music/' and the string ' [LD]' is removed from the music file path.

I am using for to loop through files as there are a number of other processes that need to be performed on each file.

```
for f in *.m3u;
    do

    # I can identify the lines using:
    fgrep -n "[LD]" "$f"
    
    # I can grab the line number using:
    ld_line=$(fgrep -c "[LD]" "$f")

    # and have tried processing the changes using sed, but it is not working..
    #sed "$ld_lines![LD]!!" "$f"

    # Ive also tried using sed as follows:
    sed '![LD]!s!music!music/_lossless!' "$f"

    # but neither of the above approaches either work or handle both modifications

  done
```

The solution does not have to use sed, whatever is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
sed '/ \[LD\]/ { s///; s,/,/_lossless/,2; }' file
```

To find lines in a file that contains the substring  `[LD]`, you may use the regular expression `/ \[LD\]/` in `sed`.  The `[` needs to be escaped to lose the special meaning that it otherwise has in a regular expression.  We don't need to escape the `]`,  but we'll escape it for the sake of symmetry.

Once we have found a line with the  `[LD]` substring, we may replace that string with nothing, i.e., remove it, with the substitution `s///`.  Using an empty regular expression will re-use the most recent expression, and the most recent expression was the one matching  `[LD]`.

The next substitution is replacing the second `/` with the string `/_lossless/`.   We pick the second match of the regular expression `/` on the line using the `2` at the end, and we use commas as delimiters for the command rather than slashes for convenience.

In a loop creating files with a `.new` filename suffix:

```bsh
for name in *.m3u; do
    sed '/ \[LD\]/ { s///; s,/,/_lossless/,2; }' -- "$name" >"$name".new
done
```

To change the files in-place on macOS, use `sed -i '' ...`.

```bsh
for name in *.m3u; do
    sed -i '' '/ \[LD\]/ { s///; s,/,/_lossless/,2; }' -- "$name"
done
```

Remember to back-up data before testing destructive commands.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`

```
for f in *.mp3; do
    var1=$(sed -E 's|(.[^/]*)(.[^[]*).*](.*)|\1/_lossless\2\3|' "$f")
    mv "$f" "var1"
done
```

**Output**

```
/music/_lossless/Miles Davis/1959 - Kind of Blue /Miles Davis - So What.mp3
```